# How To Add Scroll In CPTLegend in CorePlot

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I have a lot of entries for legend.can any one please help to make the `CPTLegend` scrollable?

Here is the code that i am using for `CPTLegend`.

```
-(void)configureLegend {
    // 1 - Get graph instance
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    // 2 - Create legend
    CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
    // 3 - Configure legen
    theLegend.numberOfColumns = 1;
    theLegend.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    theLegend.borderLineStyle = [CPTLineStyle lineStyle];
    theLegend.cornerRadius = 2.0;
    // 4 - Add legend to graph
    graph.legend = theLegend;     
    graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
    CGFloat legendPadding = -(self.view.bounds.size.width / 3);
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPointMake(-80, 120.0);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create scrollView and add legend. It is workaround but work. Example code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 450)];
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, 5000);
[scrollView.layer addSublayer:self.hostView.hostedGraph.legend];
[self.hostView addSubview:scrollView];
```

P.S. you should calculate coordinates for legend and scrollview and contentSize for scrollview

Answer (score 3):

There is an outstanding [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=335) for this, but there's currently no built-in support for scrollable legends. You can try to make everything fit by adjusting the text and swatch size, the margins, and the number of rows and columns. The alternative is to make your own scrolling legend using a custom view and positioning it in front of the graph.